# Metadata Update Metadata WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error Close

Tags: metadata

im new into deploying Solana Tokens. So im working on Devnet. Everytime i want to update the Metadata on token-creator-lac-vercel i get this error:

WalletSendTransactionError: Unexpected error
Close

The Wallet i use for updating the Token is the wallet that has mint authority. What am i doing wrong? Or is this just not possible with Devnet Tokens?

Regards

Simon

Comment: The tool you're using isn't part of the Solana core tooling, so it's unlikely someone will have an answer for you here. I suggest you reach out to Jacob Creech, the creator of the tool, directly.

Comment: Did you find the answer because i'm having the same issues.